# which version of cloudshell-shell and cloudshell-shell-core should I use?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, endevor, quali-cloudshell

I'm developing a CloudShell shell and would like it to run on all CloudShell version >= 8.1.

I require both cloudshell-shell and cloudshell-shell-core packages.
Which version of both packages should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudshell-Shell-Core & Cloudshell-Core are not dependent on server version.

This means that you can develop your shells with the latest versions of Cloudshell-Shell-Core (and Cloudshell-Core) for all Cloudshell server versions.